# Maintaining count of XML elements using Xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am a beginner in using Java programming particularly using Xpath to parse an XML file.
I am trying to develop a system that routes flights according to their weightings. I want to:

Maintain a count of flights for each location;
The system should accept a location and return the number and country to route a flight to. For every 4 flights to Japan, route the next 2 flights to China then route the next 2 flights to India and loop and to return count, continent, location name, country and weight.

I would appreciate any assistance please.

I can pass the XML data of and retrieve the different element nodes using Xpath. I attempted using SAX and STAX but prefered this method as it was clear and concise when constructing the expressions.

**XML File Example:**

```
<continent>
    <location name = "asia">
              <country>Japan</country>
              <code>0000011111</code>
              <weight>10</weight>
      </location>
      <location name = "asia">
              <country>China</country>
              <code>0000022222</code>
              <weight>1</weight>
      </location>
</continent>
```

**Java Sample Code:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
  FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("c:/continents.xml"));

  DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

  DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

  Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

  XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

  System.out.println("*************************");
  String expression = "/continent/location";
  System.out.println(expression);
  String name = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);
  System.out.println(name);

  System.out.println("**********Parse XML File***************");
  expression = "/continent/location/country|//number|//weight";
  System.out.println(expression);
  NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
  for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
      System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()); 
  }

  System.out.println("*************************");
  expression = "/continent/location[@name='asia']/number";
  System.out.println(expression);
  nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
  for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
      System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()); 
  }

  System.out.println("*************************");
  expression = "//location[country='China']";
  System.out.println(expression);
  Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
  if(null != node) {
    nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0;null!=nodeList && i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
      Node nod = nodeList.item(i);
      if(nod.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getNodeName() + " : " + nod.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don’t understand your goal.  In both your title and in your question, you mention wanting to obtain a count of certain flights.  But then you add “For every 4 flights to Japan, route the next 2 flights to China then route the next 2 flights to India and loop and to return count, continent, location name, country and weight.”  So, despite your title, it sounds like you need to return more than just an integer count.  Which is it?

Comment: I want to return the integer count of each flight and use that to route the next flight to the next country while also returning the country name. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Your requirements statement is very unclear; it always helps if you include some representative input and output to show what you are trying to achieve. And it's clear that "maintaining a count" is not part of your requirement, it is a step that, for some reason, you think is likely to form part of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I understand your goal, but if you just want to count how many flights are to a particular country, you can count the matching elements:

```
NodeList matches = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(
    "//country[text()='" + country + "']",
    xmlDocument,
    XPathConstants.NODESET);

int matchCount = matches.getLength();
```

Comment: I want to use a if statement, for example if Japan count is equal to 6 return japan, else if Japan is equal to 7 return china else if China is equal to 9 return India. Please note this is not limited to a if statement, anything other method would be fine to achieve this.

Comment: And what is stopping you from doing that?  Those are simple if/else statements.  You can change or copy the above code so it applies to "Japan" or "China" easily.